# PHP shuffle, multiple loop

Tags: php

I want to shuffle 2 loops (or function) in the same correct order, in PHP.

The code currently looks like:

`<div class="overlay">`

```
<?php

    // Get the list of all files with .jpg extension in the directory and save it in an array named $images
    $directory = "uploads/_gallery/*.jpg";

    // Create an array of images found in the uploads directory
    $images = glob($directory);

    // Randomise/shuffle the images
    shuffle($images);

    foreach( $images as $image ):
        if ($image) { ?>
            <div class="slide">
                <?php echo "<img src='" . $image . "'>"; ?>
            </div>
        <? }
    endforeach;

?>
```

`</div>`

`<div class="grid">`

```
<?php

    // Get the list of all files with .jpg extension in the directory and save it in an array named $images
    $directory = "uploads/_gallery/thumbs/*.jpg";

    // Create an array of images found in the uploads directory
    $images = glob($directory);

    // Randomise/shuffle the images
    shuffle($images);

    foreach( $images as $image ):

        if ($image) { ?>
            <figure class="unit_25">
                <?php echo "<img src='" . $image . "'>"; ?>
            </figure>
        <? }

    endforeach;

?>
```

`</div>`

I've tried creating two separate image arrays and merging those with Shuffle, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the file has the same name in both directory.
So shuffle `$images` and then use `basename($images)` to get the filename :

```
$directory = "uploads/_gallery/*.jpg";
$images = glob($directory);
shuffle($images);


// For full sized images
foreach ($images as $image) {
    // Your stuff
}

// For thumbnails
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $basename = basename($image);
    $thumbnailPath = "uploads/_gallery/thumbs/". $basename;
    // Your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply @JesusTheHun (fun nick btw).
I tried your suggestion, but the thumbs are loading the top most base directory, not the thumbnail directory. Should I wrap each foreach in a function?

Comment: Did you just copy my code ? Because I forgot a slash in the thumbnail path (edited now). Is the path correct when you look at your html render ? If yes and it doesn't work, then I don't understand the result you expect

Comment: To answer your previous question: and I realised this might be the issue, the thumbs have the same name besides, filename_1_thumb.jpg.

And yes, I did add the slash to the thumbnail path

Comment: So, I renamed the images and change this: `<?php echo "<img src='" . $image . "'>"; ?>` to `<?php echo "<img src='" . $thumbnailPath . "'>"; ?>`. And it works. Thanks a million!