# Foreach loop shuffled on output

Tags: php, glob, shuffle

Is there a simple way to get the result of this `foreach` loop shuffled on output at each page load?

```
foreach(glob('images/fotoalbum/*.*') as $file)
```

Comment: `$files = glob('images/fotoalbum/*.*'); shuffle($files); foreach($files as $file)` Something like this?

Comment: can you show an example of the result you want to achieve?

Comment: @DavidChen https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments/296481#296481

Comment: @Muiter where is your coding attempt to shuffle?

Comment: @mickmackusa I believe the OP should close their own question. The example I provided is the [first example on the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php#refsect1-function.shuffle-examples). This is a common case of just RTM.

Comment: Did you do ANY research before posting? RTM?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528644/php-shuffle-multiple-loop

Comment: Most of you have a degree in scripting or working daily with it. I don't. I did not realize that that  a glob function also returns an 'normal' array that can be shuffled.

Comment: Did you try?  I don't have a degree.  Did you even bother to look in the manual?

Comment: If you don't know that the glob function returns an array then you are not searching to shuffle an array.

Comment: Again, RTM -- `glob()` is in there and it tells you all about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't shuffle after output but you can before.

try this

```
$dir=glob('images/fotoalbum/*.*');
shuffle($dir);
foreach($dir as $file){
//operation here
}
```

Comment: Please do not answer this poor question.

Comment: why man ? is it duplicate

Comment: DEFINITELY  A DUPLICATE  "How to shuffle an array?"  Come on!  But I have been here long enough to know that when low rep users get an upvote, they aren't going to delete their answer.  DavidChen could have answered this before you, but didn't.  Why do you think that is?

Comment: should i delete? why?

Comment: You no longer can because the OP has accepted your answer.  SO continues to rot.  When users ask questions without putting for ANY effort, they lean on SO like a crutch.  They never get better, they never learn.  SO gets more and more bloated with duplicate questions that must be moderated and closed/deleted.  This means WASTED volunteer time.  This all part of horrible cycle where people are being selfish and/or lazy.